# ErrorException in dataController.php line 98: Undefined property: stdClass::$id Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to the the "id" value from a JSON request. But i am getting this error Undefined property: stdClass::$id Laravel.

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent());
foreach ($data->data as $data){
            $id = $data->id;


  $modsyPrice = floor($data->modsyPrice);
}
```

Here is my Json:

```
{"data":{"0":{"ID":"1","Name":"3 Piece Roundabout Candle Holders","Url": 

"http://url","ModsyStatus":"0","weRplayStatus"

:"0", "ModsyPrice" :"39.95", "weRplayPrice":"39.95","activeLoader":true} }}
```

Comment: Start with `print_r($data)`

Comment: [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [Name] => 3 Piece Roundabout Candle Holders
                )

Comment: same error :( .

Comment: Now think what is wrong with your code.

Comment: @waleed bin khalid try below code it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID` with upper case : `$id = $data->ID;`

the same with : `ModsyPrice`

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:Your array is multidimensional.

```
/*$json = '{"data":{"0":{"ID":"1","Name":"3 Piece Roundabout Candle Holders","Url": 

"http://url","ModsyStatus":"0","weRplayStatus"

:"0", "ModsyPrice" :"39.95", "weRplayPrice":"39.95","activeLoader":true} }}';*/


$json =json_decode($request->getContent(),true); //get your json
$array = json_decode($json,true);
//print_r($array);
    foreach ($array['data'] as $data){
                $id = $data['ID'];
                $modsyPrice = floor($data['ModsyPrice']);
    }
echo $id."<br/>";
echo $modsyPrice;
```